# Conan - Don't know how to make vcvarsall.bat

Tags: c++, c, boost, conan

I'm currently trying to use boost_system 1.69.0 as a dependency in a project using the conan package manager. I have a completely up to date windows 10 professional version with entirely up to date python, visual studio 2019, Microsoft MPI, and conan versions,

My conanfile looks like this:

```
[requires]
boost_system/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable

[generators]
cmake_find_package
```

From my 'build' directory I am running this command:

```
conan install .. --build missing
```

My output is the following:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.476]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

D:\dev\c++\rest\build>conan install .. --build missing
Configuration:
[settings]
arch=x86_64
arch_build=x86_64
build_type=Release
compiler=Visual Studio
compiler.runtime=MD
compiler.version=16
os=Windows
os_build=Windows
[options]
[build_requires]
[env]

boost_system/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable: WARN: Package is corrupted, removing folder: C:\.conan\d8b70d\1
conanfile.txt: Installing package
Requirements
    boost_config/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable from 'bincrafters' - Cache
    boost_predef/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable from 'bincrafters' - Cache
    boost_system/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable from 'bincrafters' - Cache
    boost_winapi/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable from 'bincrafters' - Cache
Python requires
    boost_base/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable
Packages
    boost_config/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable:5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9 - Cache
    boost_predef/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable:5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9 - Cache
    boost_system/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable:1cfc588b26e59ddc9e1094237b6c5153e7f2f0bc - Build
    boost_winapi/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable:5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9 - Cache
Build requirements
    boost_build/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable from 'bincrafters' - Cache
    boost_generator/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable from 'bincrafters' - Cache
Build requirements packages
    boost_build/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable:456f15897172eef340fcbac8a70811f2beb26a93 - Cache
    boost_generator/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable:6ec6439c54a97da1cfddff786d1ea15988300369 - Cache

boost_build/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable: Already installed!
boost_config/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable: Already installed!
boost_predef/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable: Already installed!
boost_generator/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable: Already installed!
boost_winapi/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable: Already installed!
boost_system/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable: Applying build-requirement: boost_generator/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable
boost_system/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable: Applying build-requirement: boost_build/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable
boost_system/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable: WARN: Build folder is dirty, removing it: C:\.conan\0d1287\1
boost_system/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable: Copying sources to build folder
boost_system/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable: Building your package in C:\.conan\0d1287\1
boost_system/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable: Generator boost created jamroot
boost_system/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable: Generator boost created boostcpp.jam
boost_system/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable: Generator boost created project-config.jam
boost_system/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable: Generator boost created short_path.cmd
boost_system/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable: Calling build()
boost_system/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable: C:\.conan\0d1287\1: b2 -j8 -d+1 -a --hash=yes --debug-configuration --layout=system    system-build
notice: found boost-build.jam at C:/Users/gamer/.conan/data/boost_build/1.69.0/bincrafters/stable/package/456f15897172eef340fcbac8a70811f2beb26a93/share/boost-build/boost-build.jam
notice: loading Boost.Build from C:/Users/gamer/.conan/data/boost_build/1.69.0/bincrafters/stable/package/456f15897172eef340fcbac8a70811f2beb26a93/share/boost-build/src/kernel
C:/Users/gamer/.conan/data/boost_build/1.69.0/bincrafters/stable/package/456f15897172eef340fcbac8a70811f2beb26a93/share/boost-build/src/util\os.jam:50: Unescaped special character in argument ([^.]*)$
C:/Users/gamer/.conan/data/boost_build/1.69.0/bincrafters/stable/package/456f15897172eef340fcbac8a70811f2beb26a93/share/boost-build/src/util\os.jam:204: Unescaped special character in argument os:
C:/Users/gamer/.conan/data/boost_build/1.69.0/bincrafters/stable/package/456f15897172eef340fcbac8a70811f2beb26a93/share/boost-build/src/util\os.jam:205: Unescaped special character in argument os:
    notice: Searching 'C:\Users\gamer' 'C:\Users\gamer' 'C:\Users\gamer\.conan\data\boost_build\1.69.0\bincrafters\stable\package\456f15897172eef340fcbac8a70811f2beb26a93\share\boost-build\src/kernel' 'C:\Users\gamer\.conan\data\boost_build\1.69.0\bincrafters\stable\package\456f15897172eef340fcbac8a70811f2beb26a93\share\boost-build\src\kernel' 'C:/Users/gamer/.conan/data/boost_build/1.69.0/bincrafters/stable/package/456f15897172eef340fcbac8a70811f2beb26a93/share/boost-build/src/kernel' 'C:/Users/gamer/.conan/data/boost_build/1.69.0/bincrafters/stable/package/456f15897172eef340fcbac8a70811f2beb26a93/share/boost-build/src/util' 'C:/Users/gamer/.conan/data/boost_build/1.69.0/bincrafters/stable/package/456f15897172eef340fcbac8a70811f2beb26a93/share/boost-build/src/build' 'C:/Users/gamer/.conan/data/boost_build/1.69.0/bincrafters/stable/package/456f15897172eef340fcbac8a70811f2beb26a93/share/boost-build/src/tools' 'C:/Users/gamer/.conan/data/boost_build/1.69.0/bincrafters/stable/package/456f15897172eef340fcbac8a70811f2beb26a93/share/boost-build/src/contrib' 'C:/Users/gamer/.conan/data/boost_build/1.69.0/bincrafters/stable/package/456f15897172eef340fcbac8a70811f2beb26a93/share/boost-build/src/.' for site-config configuration file 'site-config.jam'.
    notice: Configuration file 'site-config.jam' not found in 'C:\Users\gamer' 'C:\Users\gamer' 'C:\Users\gamer\.conan\data\boost_build\1.69.0\bincrafters\stable\package\456f15897172eef340fcbac8a70811f2beb26a93\share\boost-build\src/kernel' 'C:\Users\gamer\.conan\data\boost_build\1.69.0\bincrafters\stable\package\456f15897172eef340fcbac8a70811f2beb26a93\share\boost-build\src\kernel' 'C:/Users/gamer/.conan/data/boost_build/1.69.0/bincrafters/stable/package/456f15897172eef340fcbac8a70811f2beb26a93/share/boost-build/src/kernel' 'C:/Users/gamer/.conan/data/boost_build/1.69.0/bincrafters/stable/package/456f15897172eef340fcbac8a70811f2beb26a93/share/boost-build/src/util' 'C:/Users/gamer/.conan/data/boost_build/1.69.0/bincrafters/stable/package/456f15897172eef340fcbac8a70811f2beb26a93/share/boost-build/src/build' 'C:/Users/gamer/.conan/data/boost_build/1.69.0/bincrafters/stable/package/456f15897172eef340fcbac8a70811f2beb26a93/share/boost-build/src/tools' 'C:/Users/gamer/.conan/data/boost_build/1.69.0/bincrafters/stable/package/456f15897172eef340fcbac8a70811f2beb26a93/share/boost-build/src/contrib' 'C:/Users/gamer/.conan/data/boost_build/1.69.0/bincrafters/stable/package/456f15897172eef340fcbac8a70811f2beb26a93/share/boost-build/src/.'.
    notice: Searching 'C:\Users\gamer' 'C:\Users\gamer' 'C:\Users\gamer\.conan\data\boost_build\1.69.0\bincrafters\stable\package\456f15897172eef340fcbac8a70811f2beb26a93\share\boost-build\src/kernel' 'C:\Users\gamer\.conan\data\boost_build\1.69.0\bincrafters\stable\package\456f15897172eef340fcbac8a70811f2beb26a93\share\boost-build\src\kernel' 'C:/Users/gamer/.conan/data/boost_build/1.69.0/bincrafters/stable/package/456f15897172eef340fcbac8a70811f2beb26a93/share/boost-build/src/kernel' 'C:/Users/gamer/.conan/data/boost_build/1.69.0/bincrafters/stable/package/456f15897172eef340fcbac8a70811f2beb26a93/share/boost-build/src/util' 'C:/Users/gamer/.conan/data/boost_build/1.69.0/bincrafters/stable/package/456f15897172eef340fcbac8a70811f2beb26a93/share/boost-build/src/build' 'C:/Users/gamer/.conan/data/boost_build/1.69.0/bincrafters/stable/package/456f15897172eef340fcbac8a70811f2beb26a93/share/boost-build/src/tools' 'C:/Users/gamer/.conan/data/boost_build/1.69.0/bincrafters/stable/package/456f15897172eef340fcbac8a70811f2beb26a93/share/boost-build/src/contrib' 'C:/Users/gamer/.conan/data/boost_build/1.69.0/bincrafters/stable/package/456f15897172eef340fcbac8a70811f2beb26a93/share/boost-build/src/.' for user-config configuration file 'user-config.jam'.
    notice: Configuration file 'user-config.jam' not found in 'C:\Users\gamer' 'C:\Users\gamer' 'C:\Users\gamer\.conan\data\boost_build\1.69.0\bincrafters\stable\package\456f15897172eef340fcbac8a70811f2beb26a93\share\boost-build\src/kernel' 'C:\Users\gamer\.conan\data\boost_build\1.69.0\bincrafters\stable\package\456f15897172eef340fcbac8a70811f2beb26a93\share\boost-build\src\kernel' 'C:/Users/gamer/.conan/data/boost_build/1.69.0/bincrafters/stable/package/456f15897172eef340fcbac8a70811f2beb26a93/share/boost-build/src/kernel' 'C:/Users/gamer/.conan/data/boost_build/1.69.0/bincrafters/stable/package/456f15897172eef340fcbac8a70811f2beb26a93/share/boost-build/src/util' 'C:/Users/gamer/.conan/data/boost_build/1.69.0/bincrafters/stable/package/456f15897172eef340fcbac8a70811f2beb26a93/share/boost-build/src/build' 'C:/Users/gamer/.conan/data/boost_build/1.69.0/bincrafters/stable/package/456f15897172eef340fcbac8a70811f2beb26a93/share/boost-build/src/tools' 'C:/Users/gamer/.conan/data/boost_build/1.69.0/bincrafters/stable/package/456f15897172eef340fcbac8a70811f2beb26a93/share/boost-build/src/contrib' 'C:/Users/gamer/.conan/data/boost_build/1.69.0/bincrafters/stable/package/456f15897172eef340fcbac8a70811f2beb26a93/share/boost-build/src/.'.
    notice: Searching '.' for project-config configuration file 'project-config.jam'.
    notice: Loading project-config configuration file 'project-config.jam' from '.'.
    notice: will use 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.23.28105/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe' for msvc, condition <toolset>msvc-16.0
    notice: [msvc-cfg] condition: '<toolset>msvc-16.0/<architecture>/<address-model>', setup: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.23.28105/bin/Hostx64/vcvarsall.bat'
    notice: [msvc-cfg] condition: '<toolset>msvc-16.0/<architecture>/<address-model>32', setup: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.23.28105/bin/Hostx64/vcvarsall.bat'
    notice: [msvc-cfg] condition: '<toolset>msvc-16.0/<architecture>x86/<address-model>', setup: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.23.28105/bin/Hostx64/vcvarsall.bat'
    notice: [msvc-cfg] condition: '<toolset>msvc-16.0/<architecture>x86/<address-model>32', setup: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.23.28105/bin/Hostx64/vcvarsall.bat'
    notice: [msvc-cfg] condition: '<toolset>msvc-16.0/<architecture>/<address-model>64', setup: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.23.28105/bin/Hostx64/vcvarsall.bat'
    notice: [msvc-cfg] condition: '<toolset>msvc-16.0/<architecture>x86/<address-model>64', setup: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.23.28105/bin/Hostx64/vcvarsall.bat'
    notice: [msvc-cfg] condition: '<toolset>msvc-16.0/<architecture>ia64/<address-model>', setup: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.23.28105/bin/Hostx64/vcvarsall.bat'
    notice: [msvc-cfg] condition: '<toolset>msvc-16.0/<architecture>ia64/<address-model>64', setup: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.23.28105/bin/Hostx64/vcvarsall.bat'
    notice: [msvc-cfg] condition: '<toolset>msvc-16.0/<architecture>arm/<address-model>', setup: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.23.28105/bin/Hostx64/vcvarsall.bat'
    notice: [msvc-cfg] condition: '<toolset>msvc-16.0/<architecture>arm/<address-model>32', setup: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.23.28105/bin/Hostx64/vcvarsall.bat'
    ===============MPI Auto-configuration===============
    Found Microsoft MPI: C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI
    Found Microsoft MPI SDK: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI
    MPI build features:
    <include>/C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/MPI/Include <address-model>64:<library-path>/C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/MPI/Lib/x64 <library-path>/C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/MPI/Lib/x86 <find-static-library>msmpi <toolset>msvc:<define>_SECURE_SCL=0
    MPI launcher: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\mpiexec.exe" -n
    ====================================================
    don't know how to make <p/C:/.conan/0d1287/1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\Hostx64\vcvarsall.bat
    ...found 120 targets...
    ...updating 15 targets...
    ...can't find 1 target...
    ...can't make 2 targets...
    ...skipped <pbin\standalone\msvc\ab605d3a191801849fe1e1e55b908353>msvc-setup.read for lack of <p/C:/.conan/0d1287/1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\Hostx64\vcvarsall.bat...
    ...skipped <pbin\standalone\msvc\ab605d3a191801849fe1e1e55b908353>msvc-setup.bat for lack of <p/C:/.conan/0d1287/1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\Hostx64\vcvarsall.bat...
    ...skipped <pbin\system\build\aca5cb0fcccc3d2990e4e006ef019df6>error_code.obj for lack of <pbin\standalone\msvc\ab605d3a191801849fe1e1e55b908353>msvc-setup.nup...
    ...skipped <pbin\system\build\aca5cb0fcccc3d2990e4e006ef019df6>libboost_system.lib for lack of <pbin\system\build\aca5cb0fcccc3d2990e4e006ef019df6>error_code.obj...
    ...skipped <psystem\lib>libboost_system.lib for lack of <pbin\system\build\aca5cb0fcccc3d2990e4e006ef019df6>libboost_system.lib...
    common.copy system\lib\jamroot.jam
    bin\d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e\system-lib\jamroot.jam
            1 file(s) copied.
    ...skipped 5 targets...
    ...updated 12 targets...
    boost_system/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable:
    boost_system/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable: ERROR: Package '1cfc588b26e59ddc9e1094237b6c5153e7f2f0bc' build failed
    boost_system/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable: WARN: Build folder C:\.conan\0d1287\1
    ERROR: boost_system/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable: Error in build() method, line 147
            self._build_common()
    while calling '_build_common', line 170
            self.run(" ".join(b2_command))
            ConanException: Error 1 while executing b2 -j8 -d+1 -a --hash=yes --debug-configuration --layout=system    system-build

    D:\dev\c++\rest\build>

notice: [msvc-cfg] condition: '<toolset>msvc-16.0/<architecture>ia64/<address-model>', setup: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.23.28105/bin/Hostx64/vcvarsall.bat'
notice: [msvc-cfg] condition: '<toolset>msvc-16.0/<architecture>ia64/<address-model>64', setup: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.23.28105/bin/Hostx64/vcvarsall.bat'
notice: [msvc-cfg] condition: '<toolset>msvc-16.0/<architecture>arm/<address-model>', setup: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.23.28105/bin/Hostx64/vcvarsall.bat'
notice: [msvc-cfg] condition: '<toolset>msvc-16.0/<architecture>arm/<address-model>32', setup: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.23.28105/bin/Hostx64/vcvarsall.bat'
===============MPI Auto-configuration===============
Found Microsoft MPI: C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI
Found Microsoft MPI SDK: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI
MPI build features:
<include>/C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/MPI/Include <address-model>64:<library-path>/C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/MPI/Lib/x64 <library-path>/C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/MPI/Lib/x86 <find-static-library>msmpi <toolset>msvc:<define>_SECURE_SCL=0
MPI launcher: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\mpiexec.exe" -n
====================================================
don't know how to make <p/C:/.conan/0d1287/1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\Hostx64\vcvarsall.bat
...found 120 targets...
...updating 15 targets...
...can't find 1 target...
...can't make 2 targets...
...skipped <pbin\standalone\msvc\ab605d3a191801849fe1e1e55b908353>msvc-setup.read for lack of <p/C:/.conan/0d1287/1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\Hostx64\vcvarsall.bat...
...skipped <pbin\standalone\msvc\ab605d3a191801849fe1e1e55b908353>msvc-setup.bat for lack of <p/C:/.conan/0d1287/1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\Hostx64\vcvarsall.bat...
...skipped <pbin\system\build\aca5cb0fcccc3d2990e4e006ef019df6>error_code.obj for lack of <pbin\standalone\msvc\ab605d3a191801849fe1e1e55b908353>msvc-setup.nup...
...skipped <pbin\system\build\aca5cb0fcccc3d2990e4e006ef019df6>libboost_system.lib for lack of <pbin\system\build\aca5cb0fcccc3d2990e4e006ef019df6>error_code.obj...
...skipped <psystem\lib>libboost_system.lib for lack of <pbin\system\build\aca5cb0fcccc3d2990e4e006ef019df6>libboost_system.lib...
common.copy system\lib\jamroot.jam
bin\d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e\system-lib\jamroot.jam
        1 file(s) copied.
...skipped 5 targets...
...updated 12 targets...
boost_system/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable:
boost_system/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable: ERROR: Package '1cfc588b26e59ddc9e1094237b6c5153e7f2f0bc' build failed
boost_system/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable: WARN: Build folder C:\.conan\0d1287\1
ERROR: boost_system/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable: Error in build() method, line 147
        self._build_common()
while calling '_build_common', line 170
        self.run(" ".join(b2_command))
        ConanException: Error 1 while executing b2 -j8 -d+1 -a --hash=yes --debug-configuration --layout=system    system-build
```

It looks like it is searching for a vcvarsall.bat which it believes should be located in VC\Tools\MSVC...\bin\Hostx64\, but in actuality vcvarsall.bat is located in VC\Auxillary\build. I've tried creating a shortcut to this and even copying and pasting it to no avail. This problem is tearing at the edge of my sanity so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a strong reason to use the modularized boost version from bincrafters? If not, you might try with the monolithic boost package available in conan-center (the new one that doesn't have user/channel), that is quite tested too, so that might help. Also, for support and discussion, https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues might be a better channel.

Comment: @drodi boost_system is actually a dependency of another package I want to use. I'm using boost_system as the sole dependency because I have isolated it as the problem child. Is there a way to override the dependency requirement of another dependency?

Comment: Yes, dependencies can be overriden and replaced by your own ones, but only if the package name is the same. In this case it is not possible, because one package name is ``boost_system`` and the other is ``boost`` so they are considered different, and if you tried to use both, it will conflict. Which is the dependency you are trying to use? The community is moving now quickly to the new https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index repo, because it automatically builds the binaries and is more convenient, maybe you can find your dependency there soon.

Comment: I was using cpprestsdk and nlohmann_json when the errors mentioning boost_system began to crop up, but I have also ran into this problem when trying to use boost_asio.

Comment: boost_asio wouldn't be a problem, because it is also a boost library, will be in the monolithic boost too. nlohmann_json is already in conan-center, so I guess the missing important part is cpprestsdk. That is a bit complex, but I hope it will eventually be contributed to conan-center (soon).

Comment: did you try to set the environment manually by running `vcvarsall` before running command command?

Comment: Interesting, that worked. (though i imagine it shouldn't be a required step, the package should be able to correctly find it in the first place.)

Comment: Update: I was wrong, still doesnt work when running vcvarsall before conan install

Comment: This is a hard question to answer because replicating your full environment is difficult, but just to check something easy: are you definitely running conan/compilation from a visual-studio cmd window, not a normal cmd window? It should be listed as "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2017" or similar. Probably a dumb thought but thought I'd mention it anyway.

Comment: A bit dated now i suppose, but I was running it from a standard command prompt.